# window.location.href is not working in my window

Tags: ajax, jquery, window, xampp

I have a website uses ajax to post the data to mysql db along with php. This problem (non working of "window.location.href") started 3 days before when I accidently deleted xampp folder, I had a backup of all root files so I backed up all. But till then this function is not redirecting to the another page only in my system (have checked with main site at "http://www.slitify.com/WS0002/source/pages/notifications.html", and the same page at localhost, in different browsers, in windows xp mode, in different login account of my pc). These pages work fine when I access the site from my mobile, or from any other PC.

Have reinstalled xampp, have updated windows but none of the things is working; please suggest if anybody have any idea for the cause of the problem?

Please refer the following mark up:
http://www.slitify.com/WS0002/source/pages/notifications.html
This is working fine on every other browser apart from the browsers installed on my laptop
Please refer the below markup which is for above link:

Comment: Can you please post your markup and script?

Comment: Thanks Kishor for your time ; I tried entring markup but its aa long code and stackoverflow wants me to format it, will be able to lokk at the folloing url this is the same one and working at all other PCs apart from my coding laptop http://www.slitify.com/WS0002/source/pages/notifications.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying Debugging your Javascript.

Place check point through FireBug on window.location.href line in your code.

Step in through FireBug option and see where the Control is going whether it is reaching your code or if other JS is executing or Overriding yours.

Check Console for any JS error

Comment: Thanks now its working, there was a problem in php script which was not submitting the data sucessfully in db, and that is why further ajax function was not working thanks to all of you..